# Is grub-customizer still available?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, manjaro

I'm trying to install the GUI grub-customizer on Manjaro (5.13.13-1), but it'll only give the `error: target not found: grub-customizer`. And I see nothing online about it being down (retracted from the repository).

Comment: As per [manjaro.org](https://discover.manjaro.org/applications/grub-customizer) it's there and should be installable with pacman. Maybe your available repos aren't right for your Manjaro version?

Comment: 5.13.13-1 is the kernel you run. Could you please update your question with the distro version as well as that's what determines whether the repos can work? You'll find it with command `cat /etc/*release`.

Comment: Don't have **Manjaro**, but on **EndeavourOS** is located in the community repo: community/grub-customizer 5.1.0-2